# Sending a json serialized object containing a escaped string using HttpWebRequest on mono

Tags: json, mono, xamarin.ios, httpwebrequest, monomac

The requirement serialize a class and send it to the server.

Dev environment:

MonoDevelop 3.0.6

Runtime:
    Mono 2.10.9 (tarball)

```
GTK 2.24.10

GTK# (2.12.0.0)
```

Operating System:

```
Mac OS X 10.7.4
```

The class contains a string with an escaped double quote in it.

```
class CustomClass
{
    public string foo = "hi!\""; 
}
```

The issue is that when I serialize it, encode it and create a URI object, the backslash used to escape double quote in the variable foo is converted into a forward slash, thus breaking the json.

Below are values of the different variables of the URI instance

```
Uri:
http://myserver/hello_world/0/{"foo":"hi!/""}

AbsoluteUri:
http://myserver/hello_world/0/%7B%22foo%22%3A%22hi%21/%22%22%7D

OriginalString:
http://myserver/hello_world/0/%7B%22foo%22%3A%22hi%21%5C%22%22%7D
```

The HttpWebRequest send the value `"http://myserver/hello_world/0/{"foo":"hi!/""}"` to the server, but for my requirement it should use the OriginalString to get a valid response from the server.

If i test the code on .NET the OriginalString is being sent to the server by the HttpWebRequest class, but there is additional code (hack) which doesn't work on mono mac

```
string paq = requestUri.PathAndQuery;
FieldInfo flagsFieldInfo = typeof(Uri).GetField("m_Flags", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
ulong flags = (ulong)flagsFieldInfo.GetValue(requestUri);
flags &= ~((ulong)0x30); // Flags.PathNotCanonical|Flags.QueryNotCanonical
flagsFieldInfo.SetValue(requestUri, flags);
```

The code :

```
object messageObject = new CustomClass();

//try 1
//string jsonString = Uri.EscapeUriString(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message2));

//try 2
//string jsonString = Uri.EscapeDataString(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message2));

//try 3

string jsonString = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(messageObject));

Uri uri = new Uri(string.Format("http://myserver/hello_world/0/{0}", jsonString)); 

//try 4:
//HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri.AbsoluteUri);

//try 5
//HttpWebRequest request =(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(string.Format("http://myserver/hello_world/0/{0}",jsonString));

//try 6
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri.OriginalString);

try
{
    using (HttpWebResponse resp = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
    {
        var reader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
        string jsonResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
} 
catch (WebException wex)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(wex.ToString());
}
```

As you can see I have tried using Uri.EscapeUriString, Uri.EscapeDataString and System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode and using the AbsouluteUri and OriginalString to create the WebRequest instance and also creating it using a string.

I have also tried using the following code in the config.

```
<uri>
    <schemeSettings>
        <clear/>
        <add name="http" genericUriParserOptions="DontUnescapePathDotsAndSlashes"/>
    </schemeSettings>
</uri>
```

But none of the methods work and the encoding is lost when the request in created.

Any ideas to get this to work will be appreciated.

**Update:**

I have tried a lot of things including testing with some 3rd party open source code, but still faced the same issue when sending in an encoded url.

I modified the code to use WebClient instead of WebRequest but still no luck.

So the solution that worked for me on both MonoMac an MonoTouch(simulator, i haven't tested it on the device) was to create the request using TcpClient.

```
using (TcpClient tc = new TcpClient()) {
tc.Connect ("myserver", 80);

using (NetworkStream ns = tc.GetStream()) {
    using (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(ns)) {
                    using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(ns)) {
                        sw.Write("GET /hello_world/0/%7B%22foo%22:%22hi!%5C%22%22%7D HTTP/1.1 Host:myserver \r\n\r\n");
                        sw.Flush ();
                        string line;
                        while ((line=sr.ReadLine())!=null)
                            Console.Write (line);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Also experience the same behavior on MonoTouch

Comment: What does `foo = @"hi!""";` get you?

Comment: @ruffin, Thanks for the reply. It gets me the same result in the Uri, but the AbsoluteUri and OriginalString differs. The HttpWebRequest still sends the value `"http://myserver/hello_world/0/{"foo":"hi!/""}"` to the server 

`URI
http://myserver/hello_world/0/{"foo":"hi!/""}

OriginalString
http://myserver/hello_world/0/%7B%22foo%22%3A%22hi%21%5C%22%22%7D

AbsoluteUri
http://myserver/hello_world/0/%7B%22foo%22:%22hi!/%22%22%7D`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried a lot of things including testing with some 3rd party open source code, but still faced the same issue when sending in an encoded url.

I modified the code to use WebClient instead of WebRequest but still no luck.

So the solution that worked for me on both MonoMac an MonoTouch(simulator, i haven't tested it on the device) was to create the request using TcpClient.

```
using (TcpClient tc = new TcpClient()) {
tc.Connect ("myserver", 80);

using (NetworkStream ns = tc.GetStream()) {
    using (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(ns)) {
        using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(ns)) {
            sw.Write("GET /hello_world/0/%7B%22foo%22:%22hi!%5C%22%22%7D HTTP/1.1 Host:myserver \r\n\r\n");
            sw.Flush ();
            string line;
            while ((line=sr.ReadLine())!=null)
                Console.Write (line);
            }
        }
    }
}
```